# Variable declaration in Exasol

Tags: local-variables, exasolution

I am new with Exasol and haven't found out how one can declare a variable as in SQL. In SQL I would write:

`DECLARE @variable_name datatype [ = initial_value ]`

And in Exasol? Many thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

In Exasol a stored procedure is described as a 'SCRIPT'. Script variables are typed dynamically.
You can use script variables in the following way: 
`local msg='Hello'`
https://docs.exasol.com/content/database_concepts/scripting/general_script_language.htm

In ExaPlus (user interface) you could use "define".
Example 
`define msg='Hello';`
https://optimumretrieval.wordpress.com/2016/12/15/using-variables-in-exaplus/

Answer (score 0):

There is such feature in ExaPlus client. It's described in User Manual.

But you have to keep a few things in mind:

- ExaPlus GUI is no longer available starting from Exasol 6.1;
- It is purely client-side feature. There are no variables in other clients or DBMS itself;

But you may still build your query normally with placeholders pointing to variables using any programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
define stuff='hello';

SELECT * FROM table WHERE column=':stuff';
```